# Get delegate objectName from qml to python

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I have an ListView, and inside of this i have delegate Rectangle, and inside Rectangle, i have Image object. So i want to get Image objectName into python PyQt5 file, and set for each image different sources!

```
ListView { 
    model: 12 /*that mean that i have 12 images!*/
    delegate: Rectangle {
        Image {
            objectName: "img"
            source: "file:///C:/LocalDir/Project/img/11.png"
        }
    }
}



def set_property():
    self.context = QQuickWidget()
    self.context.setSource(QUrl().fromLocalFile("QML-code.qml"))
    self.rootObj = context.rootObject()
    img = self.rootObj.findChild("img") 

    if img:
        img.setProperty("source", path)
    # and so on...but i don't know how to get img delegate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going down the wrong path, delegates can be deleted and created without notifying the GUI, so accessing them individually is not the right thing to do. The strategy in the views is to pass the information through the models, in this case as you are going to get the information of the path of the image in python it is advisable to create a model based on QAbstractListModel:

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuickWidgets


class ImageModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    PathRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self._paths = []

    def addPath(self, path):
        self.beginInsertRows(
            QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount()
        )
        self._paths.append(path)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._paths)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == ImageModel.PathRole and 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount():
            return self._paths[index.row()]
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def roleNames(self):
        return {ImageModel.PathRole: b"path"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = ImageModel()
    w = QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget(
        resizeMode=QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget.SizeViewToRootObject
    )
    w.rootContext().setContextProperty("pathmodel", model)
    filename = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "main.qml"
    )
    w.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    pictures_path = QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation(
        QtCore.QStandardPaths.PicturesLocation
    )
    formats = (
        "*{}".format(fmt.data().decode())
        for fmt in QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()
    )
    for finfo in QtCore.QDir(pictures_path).entryInfoList(formats):
        model.addPath(finfo.absoluteFilePath())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle{
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListView { 
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: pathmodel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            Image {
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: Qt.resolvedUrl(model.path)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or more easily use a QStandardItemModel:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuickWidgets

PathRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    model.setItemRoleNames({PathRole: b"path"})
    w = QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget(
        resizeMode=QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget.SizeViewToRootObject
    )
    w.rootContext().setContextProperty("pathmodel", model)
    filename = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "main.qml"
    )
    w.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    pictures_path = QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation(
        QtCore.QStandardPaths.PicturesLocation
    )
    formats = (
        "*{}".format(fmt.data().decode())
        for fmt in QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()
    )
    for finfo in QtCore.QDir(pictures_path).entryInfoList(formats):
        it = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        it.setData(finfo.absoluteFilePath(), PathRole)
        model.appendRow(it)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc, but if i won't use QAbstractListModel, could you provide some answers?

Comment: @dimatronciu If you check my code there are 2 answers: 1) used QAbstractListModel and 2) Using QStandardItemModel